# How can I get a reference to a defer function?

Tags: go

[This article](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) states: "A defer statement pushes a function call onto a list." I'm wondering if I can access the elements in that list from another place in my program and then invoke them? Can I invoke them multiple times?  I'm assuming that I have a reference to the function that has defer behavior (if that helps).

So, here's a short example of what I want to do:

```
func main {
    doStuff = func() {
        // open database connections
        // write temporary files
        // etc...

        defer func() {
            // close database connections
            // delete temporary files
            // etc...
        }()
    }

    AwesomeApplication(doStuff)
}

func AwesomeApplication(doStuff func()) {
    // Now, can I get a reference to the defer function within `doStuff`?
    // No, I can't just define the defer function somewhere an pass it
    // with `doStuff`.  Think of this as a curiosity I want to satisfy,
    // not a real use case.
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 'list' where to `defer` calls are stored are fully implementation specific so you have **no reliable way of getting to this list**.<sup>[1](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/376),[2](http://research.swtch.com/goabstract)</sup> The implementation details for the *g compiler family (albeit a bit older) can be found [in Russ Cox' research blog](http://research.swtch.com/goabstract).

Deferred functions are associated with the current goroutine ([`g->Defer`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/runtime/runtime.h?name=release-branch.go1.1#231)) and 
(in case of *g family) identified by the current stack pointer. If the current stack frame matches
the stack frame stored in the topmost `Defer` entry, this function is called.

With this knowledge it *is* possible to access the list of deferred functions using cgo.
You need to know

- the current stack pointer
- the address of the function
- the current goroutine

However, I don't recommend using this.
A general solution for the use case you're describing would be to have a function like this:

```
func setupRoutines() (setUp, tearDown func()) {
    // store db connection object and such

    return func() { /* connect db and such */ }, func() { /* close db and such */ }
}
```

In your code you could then share the `tearDown` function, which would be called using `defer`.
This way you still have the bonus of having all your database connections and such local but you're
able to share the initialization/disconnect functions.

#### Fiddle to play with

If you're really interested in playing around with `unsafe` and C, you can use the following code as a template.

inspect/runtime.c:

```
// +build gc
#include <runtime.h>

void ·FirstDeferred(void* foo) {
    foo = g->defer->fn;

    FLUSH(&foo);
}
```

inspect/inspect.go

```
package inspect

import "unsafe"

func FirstDeferred() unsafe.Pointer
```

defer.go

```
package main

import "defer/inspect"

func f(a, b int) {
    println("deferred f(", a, b, ")")
}

func main() {
    defer f(1, 2)
    println( inspect.FirstDeferred() )
}
```

This code (based on [this](http://golang.org/misc/cgo/test/backdoor/)) gives you access to the current go routine (`g`) and therefore
the `defer` attribute of it. Therefore you should be able to access the pointer to the function
and wrap it in a go `FuncVal` and return it.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation.  I was hoping it would be simpler, possibly a standard library function.  I guess I knew it wouldn't be pretty.

Comment: Sadly there is nothing in the standard library for this. However, I don't see the benefit of this as it can be modelled easily using closures. If you think it would benefit the standard library you could open a ticket. :)

Comment: I don't think my use case is appropriate for the standard library.  I agree that closures is the way to go. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Wow. Stellar answer. +1