# Can I create a function that must only be used with defer?

Tags: go, defer-keyword

For example:

```
package package

// Dear user, CleanUp must only be used with defer: defer CleanUp()
func CleanUp() {
    // some logic to check if call was deferred
    // do tear down
}
```

And in userland code:

```
func main() {
    package.CleanUp() // PANIC, CleanUp must be deferred!
}
```

But all should be fine if user runs:

```
func main() {
   defer package.CleanUp() // good job, no panic
}
```

---

Things I already tried:

```
func DeferCleanUp() {
    defer func() { /* do tear down */ }()
    // But then I realized this was exactly the opposite of what I needed
    // user doesn't need to call defer CleanUp anymore but...
}
// now if the APi is misused it can cause problems too:
defer DeferCleanUp() // a defer inception xD, question remains.
```

Comment: Even if you were able to enforce such a thing, someone could just create a function whose *only* line was a `defer package.CleanUp()`, and then call that function, effectively calling your function without a `defer` (but actually with a `defer`).

Comment: You mean `defer func(){ defer CleanUp() }`? Yea, Santa hates this kind of user :)

Comment: No, more like `func() { defer CleanUp() }()` without a `defer` on front of the outer function.

Comment: That's what I want, just like on `func main(){ defer CleanUp() }`. hole thing is to obligate to use the function with a `defer`.

Comment: I know, but I’m saying they could embed that inside of another function, e.g. `func main() { foo(); func() { defer CleanUp() }(); bar() }`, which would probably have the exact same undesirable behavior as `func main() { foo(); CleanUp(); bar() }` but still fits your constraints.

Comment: Can you say more why you want to do this?  Perhaps a different approach may satisfy the same goal?

Comment: The only thing I'm trying to avoid is somebody to call `CleanUp()` without a defer by distraction so application would panic immediately. Where it's called is not a big deal.

Comment: In other words, I would like an idiomatic way to tell that a function is only useful when deferred.

Comment: @marcio -- I don't think there is one. `mutex.Unlock()` is very, very often deferred right after the corresponding `mutex.Lock()`, but it has no special defer-me status. Sometimes you just have to document.

Comment: @twotwotwo that's sad, I'll try to ask for this feature with the Go devs, it's Christmas ;)

Comment: I doubt the go cabal would like this idea

Comment: @marcio There is sort of an ugly way of doing it but it's really shitty and I'm not writing it as an answer: If you inspect the call stack, you will see that when called deferred, one level above your function the caller's line is "}", meaning its about to exit the function, and your function was not called directly. Otherwise you will see a direct call to your function at that level.

Comment: I'm very curious to see that, how to inspect the stack? :)

Comment: @marcio I'll post it as an answer, I hope I won't get downvoted :)

Comment: don't worry, this topic is highly experimental, gophers will behave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, per OPs request and just for laughs, I'm posting this hacky approach to solving this by looking at the call stack and applying some heuristics.

**DISCLAIMER: Do not use this in real code. I don't think checking deferred is even a good thing.**

Also Note: this approach will only work if the executable and the source are on the same machine.

Link to gist: https://gist.github.com/dvirsky/dfdfd4066c70e8391dc5 (this doesn't work in the playground because you can't read the source file there)

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "io/ioutil"
    "bytes"
    "strings"
)




func isDeferred() bool {
    
    // Let's get the caller's name first
    var caller string
    if fn, _, _, ok  := runtime.Caller(1); ok {
        caller = function(fn)
    } else {
        panic("No caller")
    }
    
    // Let's peek 2 levels above this - the first level is this function,
    // The second is CleanUp()
    // The one we want is who called CleanUp()
    if _, file, line, ok  := runtime.Caller(2); ok {
        
        // now we actually need to read the source file
        // This should be cached of course to avoid terrible performance
        // I copied this from runtime/debug, so it's a legitimate thing to do :)
        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
        if err != nil {
            panic("Could not read file")
        }
        
        // now let's read the exact line of the caller 
        lines := bytes.Split(data, []byte{'\n'})
        lineText := strings.TrimSpace(string(lines[line-1]))
        fmt.Printf("Line text: '%s'\n", lineText)
        
        
        // Now let's apply some ugly rules of thumb. This is the fragile part
        // It can be improved with regex or actual AST parsing, but dude...
        return lineText == "}" ||  // on simple defer this is what we get
               !strings.Contains(lineText, caller)  || // this handles the case of defer func() { CleanUp() }()
               strings.Contains(lineText, "defer ")
        
        
    } // not ok - means we were not clled from at least 3 levels deep
    
    return false
}

func CleanUp() {
    if !isDeferred() {
        panic("Not Deferred!")
    }
    
    
}

// This should not panic
func fine() {
    defer CleanUp() 
    
    fmt.Println("Fine!")
}


// this should not panic as well
func alsoFine() {
    defer func() { CleanUp() }()
    
    fmt.Println("Also Fine!")
}

// this should panic
func notFine() {
    CleanUp() 
    
    fmt.Println("Not Fine!")
}

// Taken from the std lib's runtime/debug:
// function returns, if possible, the name of the function containing the PC.
func function(pc uintptr) string {
    fn := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
    if fn == nil {
        return ""
    }
    name := fn.Name()
    if lastslash := strings.LastIndex(name, "/"); lastslash >= 0 {
        name = name[lastslash+1:]
    }
    if period := strings.Index(name, "."); period >= 0 {
        name = name[period+1:]
    }
    name = strings.Replace(name, "·", ".", -1)
    return name
}

func main(){
    fine()
    alsoFine()
    notFine()
}
```

Comment: Thanks and wow... that's the most hacky golang thing ever. I thought you would somehow access the defer stack not the actual source code x)

Comment: @marcio thanks. If you go ahead and read `runtime` and `runtime/debug` source code, it all looks a bit like this. They're hiding the ugly under the hood. This, for example, is the source for the function that prints the stacks for panics, etc: http://golang.org/src/runtime/debug/stack.go?s=516:533#L40

Comment: Thanks for the ref. Perhaps this other answer can help to improve this implementation http://stackoverflow.com/a/18454768/438563 Maybe it can be possible to access the defer stack and look for the fn call. If it's not there, it's not deferred.

Comment: @marcio wow, that's deep. I wonder if it still works given that the runtime has been rewritten to be largely Go in 1.4. But no time to test it, I have actual code to write :)